# Flask form does not raise CSRFError for invalid token

Tags: flask, csrf, flask-wtforms

The [Flask-WTF docs](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html) state:

> When CSRF validation fails, it will raise a CSRFError.

but I'm not getting the exception.

I'm using Flask-WTF for my forms like this:

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    ...
```

In my handler I do this:

```
my_form = MyForm()
if my_form.validate_on_submit():
    ...
```

I expect the exception to be raised inside `validate_on_submit` but instead `validate_on_submit` just returns False.

Note that I am not doing this:

```
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
```

because my understanding is that is not needed if your forms depend from `FlaskForm`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you submitting an invalid CSRF token or just an invalid form? If `validate_on_submit` is returning `False` my guess without seeing the rest of your code is there is another field that is failing validation.

Comment: @PGHE, yes, I'm submitting an invalid CSRF token by editing the web page before submitting the form.  The form data is otherwise valid. Everything works if I don't edit the CSRF token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Searching through the flask-wtf repo for CSRFError](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/search?q=CSRFError&type=Code), it seems that the only time it is actually raised if you do use that

```
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
```

pattern you mentioned. It's only raised by `_error_response` in [csrf.py](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/534e1734b86c2f0907af131c11b981e6146ca57c/flask_wtf/csrf.py) which is called by the `protect` function. In contrast, for example the `validate_csrf` raises `ValidationError` when the token is invalid.

Comment: Thanks!  I wonder if this is intentional or a bug.  I'll post an issue on the WTF github page.  At least the docs should be updated.